# Run python script outside of webserver

Tags: python, django

My django app is running on an nginx/uwsgi stack. My goal is to start a python script which runs independently from the web server. By hitting a endpoint on django, it would thus fire off a non blocking script.

I've looked into using python subprocess/Popen - i'm just not sure if the script is still running on the web server or not via subprocess.Popen()

Comment: You could use Twisted, but you'd have to do a bit of wizardry with the Crochet library. It really depends on what you're trying to do. But if you're simply trying to run a script in a different process, you can just use Multiprocessing.

Comment: Well, you could use http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, that integrates nicely with Django. The asynchronous task would then run the background, and commit its potential result to a backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is for. You should use that.

Comment: So celery can run background tasks that wont die even if a uwsgi process serving django is running on dies?

Comment: After some doc reading - I didn't realize celery was separately daemonized, thus exactly what I needed. When using uwsgi however, I did find their Mules concept to be on par with celery.